# Camel-SCR ( Declarative Services ) not able to access javax.sql.DataSource

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, declarative-services

I have created datssource service with pax-jdbc-config and following URL

https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/spaces/PAXJDBC/pages/61767710/Create+DataSource+from+config

Now datasource service is available

```
karaf@root()> service:list javax.sql.DataSource
[javax.sql.DataSource]
----------------------
 dataSourceName = MySqlDS
 felix.fileinstall.filename = file:/C:/Apache/apache-karaf-4.2.0/etc/org.ops4j.datasource-MySqlDS.cfg
 osgi.jdbc.driver.class = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 osgi.jdbc.driver.name = mysql
 osgi.jndi.service.name = java:/MySqlDS
 password = root
 service.bundleid = 102
 service.factoryPid = org.ops4j.datasource
 service.id = 147
 service.pid = org.ops4j.datasource.eaeb33be-1dcc-4f56-b9f3-37f5185ad761
 service.scope = singleton
 url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
 user = root
Provided by :
 OPS4J Pax JDBC Config (102)
```

But while running my camel-scr route i am getting below error

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException: No bean could be found in the registry for: MySqlDS of type: javax.sql.DataSource
        at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.mandatoryLookupAndConvert(CamelContextHelper.java:201) ~[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.19.5]
        at org.apache.camel.util.EndpointHelper.resolveReferenceParameter(EndpointHelper.java:326) ~[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.19.5]
        at org.apache.camel.util.EndpointHelper.resolveReferenceParameter(EndpointHelper.java:308) ~[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.19.5]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.resolveAndRemoveReferenceParameter(DefaultComponent.java:415) ~[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.19.5]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.resolveAndRemoveReferenceParameter(DefaultComponent.java:394) ~[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.19.5]
        at org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlComponent.createEndpoint(SqlComponent.java:62) ~[131:org.apache.camel.camel-sql:2.19.5]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(DefaultComponent.java:116) ~[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.19.5]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:676) ~[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.19.5]
        at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:80) ~[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.19.5]
```

Camel SCR Runner snippet:

```
protected void setupCamelContext(BundleContext bundleContext, String camelContextId)throws Exception{
        super.setupCamelContext(bundleContext, camelContextId);

        getContext().setUseMDCLogging(true);

        getContext().setUseBreadcrumb(true);

        SqlComponent sql = new SqlComponent();
        getContext().addComponent("sql", sql);
    }
```

Camel Route

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
        // Add a bean to Camel context registry
        AbstractCamelRunner.getRegistry(getContext(), SimpleRegistry.class).put("testString", "this is a test");

        from("{{from}}")
        .to("sql:select * from table?dataSource=#MySqlDS&outputType=StreamList&outputClass=org.apache.camel.component.sql.ProjectModel")
        .to("log:stream")
        .split(body()).streaming()
            .to("log:row")
            .to("mock:result")
        .end();
    }
```

As i am using #MySqlDS which suppose to take it from service registry or i have to add in setupcamelcontext and how??

Answer (score 0):

Camel SQL Component expects a reference when you use the dataSource= option.

MySqlDS is the osgi.jndi.service.name and not the reference id